# Send post request from one web server to another

Tags: node.js, forms

I'm trying to send a post request from one server to another
Say I've got two servers (on node.js) running  on localhost:3000 and localhost:4000, now I'm trying to send a post request from 3000 to 4000.

I've tried this

```js
app.post('/some_routes', (req, res) => { console.log('request recieved')} )
// on recieving side, ie. localhost:4000
```

```html
<form action="localhost:4000/some_routes" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 <form>
 <!-- on sending side, ie. localhost:3000 >
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?
Also please add both client and server side snippets.

Comment: You can't do it using Javascript unless you enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on the other server (localhost:4000/some_routes) or do it in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

You can then do a post like this

```
  axios.post('/some_routes', {
    some: 'data',
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: how do i catch the post data at the other end?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same scenario and it is working, as shown below

**On Local Host 4000:**

```
router.post('/some_routes', async function(req, res) { console.log('request recieved')} );
```

**On Local Host 3000:**

```
<form name="submitForm" method="POST" action="http://localhost:4000/some_routes/">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <a href="javascript:document.submitForm.submit()">Click on the link</a>
</form>
```

The problem that I face is that it is not working on different servers.